# Knapsack formula using only weights as the recursion variable

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, top-down

I have developed a recursive formula for knapsack problem on my own without any knowledge of present solutions. Please tell me whether it is right or wrong and correct it.Thanks in advance.

```
B(S) = max (B (s-w(i)) + b(w(i)) )
```

for all `i` belonging to `n`;
notations are as usual . `S` is capacity,`B` is the answer to knapsack.

Comment: In the formula within the `max` expression, does `s` denote the sum of weights of items in `S`? If so, isn't it strange that the profit of the items is not reflected in the formula?

Comment: Does `B` refer to the _weight_ or the _profit_ of a solution?

Comment: @Codor B refers to profit of the solution

Answer (score 2):

I do not want to give you straight answer, but to direct you on the flaws of your formula, and let you figure out how to solve them.

1. Well, if you do not address the value, something must be wrong - otherwise, you just simply lose information. If you chose to "take" the item (`B(s-w(i))`) what happens to the current value?
2. In addition, what is `i`? How do you change `i` over time?
3. When talking about recursive formula, you must also mention a stop clause for it.

Comment: OP, to make amit's point 1 as clear as possible: Suppose you find a solution to some instance, and this solution does not use some item k.  Now create another problem instance that is identical to the first one, except that item k has value 1 million.  Your algorithm will again produce a solution that does not use k, since changing its value has no effect on how it runs -- but clearly k belongs in all optimal solutions.